# How to filter out a file from wildcard match when an environment is not set

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am using gnu make.

I have version like this:

```
MYLIST := $(filter-out $(if $(filter 1,$(exclude_file1)), file1.c),$(wildcard *.c))
```

It works well: when I what to filter out "file1.c", I set the environment variable, exclude_file1.

Now I want the opposite: when an environment variable is not set, I want to exclude file1.c.

Could you point me what should be the change?

Comment: _It works well_: sure of that? What you wrote is probably not what you use. Are you sure that the condition of your `if` is `$(filter 1,$(exclude_file1))`? Anyway, the answer to your question is in the GNU make manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-if. `if` has a "if true" part and a "if false" part.

Answer (score 0):

```
MYLIST := $(filter-out $(if $(filter undefined,$(origin exclude_file1)),,file1.c),$(wildcard *.c))
```

or

```
MYLIST := $(filter-out $(if $(filter-out undefined,$(origin exclude_file1)),file1.c),$(wildcard *.c))
```

or

```
MYLIST := $(filter-out $(if ${exclude_file1},,file1.c),$(wildcard *.c))
```

etc.

One advantage of the first two formulations is that they don't generate a message when the very useful `--warn-undefined-variables` is in effect.